# Scaling a view reduces the content size but increases blank margins

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to scale a horizontal `LinearLayout` that contains `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` adding

```
android:scaleX="0.6"
android:scaleY="0.6"
```

The problem is that this scales the content but increases the margin at the same time, so I cannot use the space properly. In the picture the marked white area is the space gained by scaling, but I cannot use this space (in fact, the clock on the right is cropped)

[image: Screenshot]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:scaleX="0.6"
    android:scaleY="0.6">

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:spinnersShown="false"
        android:layoutMode="opticalBounds"
        android:measureAllChildren="true" />

    <TimePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any solution to scale the view without this blank space problem?

Comment: Was the Image taken with the IDE preview?

Comment: @asafgitai yes is from IDE preview

Comment: In that case, the issue could be related only to pre Holo pickers preview. Is this issue happening to you on real devices? If yes is it happening with Holo pickers as well? http://i.stack.imgur.com/TGYQ5.png

Comment: If you cannot achieve some behavior with LinearLayout, try to use RelativeLayout.

Comment: I will try all suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you not to use xscale & yscale.
Instead what you can do is provide weight for date picker & time picker.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:spinnersShown="false"
        android:layoutMode="opticalBounds"
        android:measureAllChildren="true" />

    <TimePicker
       android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

you can add padding at sides or modify the weights as an how you want.

Comment: This doesn't work. The DatePicker and TimePicker views will overlap or not be shown fully if they don't fit on the device screen.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to use the date and time picker in a dialog instead? I think that may be your only option. I'm not aware of a way to shrink the size of the DatePicker and TimePicker the way you're trying to. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePickerFragment.

Answer (score 1):

Scalling will not change your controls size it means your data picker will take same space in your layout regardless if it is scalled up or down. only thier apperance changes